# how to excract text from web site using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i have Code like this:

```
<mat-label _ngcontent-vrc-c49="" class="filingCount ng-star-inserted">2 RRR</mat-label>
```

and i want value : 2 RRR

i tried with:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontentid"]/app-dashboard/app-itr-status/div[4]/mat-label')
print(element.text)
```

but it's give the zero

Comment: Are you waiting enough for the element to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you have to add wait until the element is visible. Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="maincontentid"]/app-dashboard/app-itr-status/div[4]/mat-label')))
print(element.text)
```

If still not working validate your locator correctness.